# Unsubscride from all my Class events at the end of my operation

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have this class that contain several events that from my main i register and update my `UI`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public delegate void event1Delegate();
    public event event1Delegate event1Handler;

    public delegate void event2Delegate();
    public event event2Delegate event2Handler;

    public delegate void FinishWorkDelegate();
    public event FinishWorkDelegate FinishWorkEventHandler;

    public void DoWork()
    {
       // bla bla
       if (FinishWorkEventHandler != null)
           FinishWorkEventHandler();
    }
}
```

And from my main `UI` register to this events inside my button clock event:

```
private void radMenuItemSimultaneouslyPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    job.event1Handler += job_event1Handler;
    job.event2Handler += job_event2Handler;
    job.FinishWorkEventHandler += job_FinishWorkEventHandler;
    job.doWork();
}
```

Now when `FinishWorkEventHandler` fired this means that my operation done:

```
private void job_OnFinishJobThreadEvent()
{
    labelStatus.Text= "Finished!";
}
```

And here i want to unsubscride to `MyClass` events so i wonder if it's OK to change this event from `FinishWorkDelegate()` into `FinishWorkDelegate(MyClass obj)` and that from here i have access to my object and in this case i can unsubscride to my events.
Is it OK to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it OK to do that ?

Yeah why not ? in fact there is already a built-in delegate for this called [`EventHandler<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), instead of creating a new delegate you can use that:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FinishWorkEventHandler;

public void DoWork()
{
     // bla bla
     if (FinishWorkEventHandler != null)
          FinishWorkEventHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Here you can replace `this` with your current instance (if you want to trigger it from outside of the class ofcourse) and then pass it to event handler.in the event handler you can access your object like this:

```
private void OnFinish(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var myObject = sender as MyClass;
   if (myObject != null)
   {
       myObject.event1Handler -= job_event1Handler;
       myObject.event2Handler -= job_event2Handler;
   }
}
```

Comment: What about unsubscribe to FinishWorkEventHandler ?

Comment: @user3328870 `myObject.FinishWorkEventHandler -=  OnFinish;`